# php with symfony website tracing request on production server

Tags: php, symfony

I have a php website using symfony2 framework .I wanted to know what would be the best method to trace incoming request on production server in order to troubleshoot client issues .The only way that i know of is using php log file in C:Windows/Temp directory .Is there any other way of tracing request and troubleshooting error with respect to such request .all the request to website are https not sure fiddler can help me in this scenario .Please let me know your feedback on the same .
Thanks

Comment: Symfony has its own log bundle called **monolog**. You can find more information about it on the Internet

Comment: How we can give an answer if we don't know what do you want to track specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than on way to log client requests.

First, Apache will log incoming requests in the /var/log/www/access.log

Secondly, Symfony has its own logging enabled by default available in app/logs/prod.log

Thirdly, you can implement client side logging and logging with monolog , example : Javascript errors => send ajax request to log endpoint => log with monolog action

Now, on what type of OS will your site run ? You speak about Windows Temp directory, will your site be hosted on Windows or UNIX servers ? configurations and available tools will then be different.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on some project where I plan to do it via [GrayLog2](https://www.graylog2.org/) (as @Christophe suggested in a 3rd solution).

I ran some local trials and it seems more than capable of logging just anything.